# JavaFX Button Click to open a local HTML Read Me File

Tags: java, javafx-8

Using JavaFX, I am looking for a way to open a local HTML ReadMe File. I know it must be too simple because I couldn't find anything out there. The Help link is located under MenuItem in the tool bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a minimal app to do what you need.
The main class is

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/res/MenuWithHtmlReader.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The FXML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.45" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onLoadHelpFile" text="Open Readme file" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" prefWidth="500.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The controller is:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    WebView webView;

    @FXML
    public void onLoadHelpFile(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onLoadHelpFile clicked" + webView);
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/res/readme.html").toExternalForm());
    }
}
```

And the help file readme.html is

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello, this is your local friendly help file. Do as I say and you will be totally safe.</p>
<p>No pianos will plummet down onto your head.</p>
<p>Probably.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I put the fxml and the html files in the res folder.
I hope that helps.